# Docker: how to manage development and production settings?

Tags: nginx, deployment, docker, workflow, dockerfile

I'm just getting started with Docker. With the official NGINX image on my OSX development machine (with Docker Machine as the Docker host) I ran up against the bug with `sendfile` and VirtualBox which means the server fails to show changes I make to files.

The workaround for this is to use a modified nginx.conf file that turns off `sendfile`. [This guy's solution](https://ejf.io/dev_blog/docker_nginx_caching/) has an instruction in the Dockerfile to copy a customised conf file into the container. Alternatively, [this guy](http://mflo.io/2015/06/28/nocache-nginx-docker-container/) maps the NGINX configuration to a new folder with modified conf file.

This kind of thing works OK locally. But what if I don't need this modification on my cloud host? How should I handle this and other differences when it comes to deployment?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could mount your custom `nginx.conf` into the container in *development* via e.g. `--volume ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` and simply omit this parameter to `docker run` in *production*.

If using [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/), the two options I would recommend are:

- Employ the limited support for [environment variable interpolation](http://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/variable-substitutio%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bn) and add something like the following under `volumes` in your container definition: `./nginx/nginx.${APP_ENV}.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`
- Use [a separate YAML file for production overrides](http://docs.docker.com/compose/production).

Comment: Thanks Evgeny, I'll do that.

Comment: Do you know how to do it on docker-compose.yml?

Comment: @Daskul just add ` - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` as an item under the `volumes` definition of the container.

Comment: yes I already have that one, but I want to change some configs when running production? Any tips how to change the config depending on environment?

Comment: I know docker compose has limited support for environment variable interpolation (https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/variable-substitution), so you _might_ be able to to something like `./nginx/nginx.${APP_ENV}.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`. Using a separate YAML file for production overrides might be a viable option here as well: https://docs.docker.com/compose/production/

Comment: thanks a lot! exactly what I need. I think you can add them up to your answer.